# Robot, or robot arm, to lift small objects a short distance

Tags: untagged

I want to create a short video for a warehousing/inventory project that I am developing. I don't have a great deal of spare cash, so can we please try to keep it sub US $200, preferably, sub $100.

My first thought was a Lego robot arm, but Lego seems so expansive. Then I just thought robot, but maybe a humanoid robot, or forklift truck robot? Let you imagination run wi1ld.

Again, my first thought was just to have a pile of RFID key fobs, since I have some lying around, and have them moved rom pile A to pile B, to represent goods in/out.

Then I thought that maybe I should use RFID stickers and stick them onto wooden blocks to represent parcels, and have a humanoid robot carry them from pile A to pile B. Or have them represent crates and have a mini forklift move them.

That's it from the rough hardware idea. Just move them from pile A to pile B, until all are moved,  then reverse it.

Wait, I take that back - pick one ***at random*** from pile A, move it past an RFID sensor, then move it to pile B - goods in, reverse at the ensue. I already have the RFID sensor.

So, whether robot arm, humanoid robot, forklift robot, or something else, what would you recommend?

I imagine that it will be coded is C, C++ or Python, but have no fear of other languages. A good IDE (or, better yet, usable in VS Code) and good support/community would be welcome, all the while, being cheap and visually impressive.

In case it's not clear, I want to be able to program the robots movement, rather than remote control it manually. And it would be useful if it could detect whether it actually managed to pick something up